# how to make vim ctags works for modern javascript

Tags: javascript, vim, ctags

I am using vim and ctags to get taglist. but for javascript, it does not works for this convention

```
MyClass.extend({
  xxx: function(){
  },
   ...
})

MyClass.prototype = {
    method : function(){ }

}

MyClass.prototype.method  = function () {
}
```

Comment: Odds are no-one's written the parser for you yet so your going to have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like the others had said: *DoctorJS* (formerly *jsctags*) is the best option.

However, integrating it with Vim by writing custom wrappers or using Vim-taglist-plus plugin, which isn't currently working, aren't good solutions.

The easiest way I've found is to install the [TagBar Vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) (**NOTE**: It's TagBar, not the old infamous TagList!).

[See my other answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/5893600#5893600).

## Edit:

There's a new project called tern.js which should replace the dead doctor.js. See the link above for more info.

Comment: Wow, you switched the answer. Guess you really enjoyed the solution. :)

Comment: Too bad the DoctorJS project is no longer maintained (at least [here](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs)). It fails to run on itself, and not only...

Comment: Yes, but the wiki in TagBar GitHub repo has a temporary fix for this - [you can revert to an earlier commit](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki).

Comment: Both DoctorJS and Tern for vim are abandonware. There is currently no good way that is documented online (which doesn't mean it doesn't exist).

Comment: Tern is, Tern for Vim is not

Answer (score 12):

As @Benoit answered, you can always setup a new languages for ctags; however in the case of JavaScript, you may want to try DoctorJS (formerly **jsctags**). From the author it is a limited JS environment that records all the functions and objects your script made and turns them into vim-compatible tags file. Here is the original post http://pcwalton.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-jsctags.html and its website: http://doctorjs.org/.

To use it with ctags I have to rename the ctags file to smt like `ex-ctags` and write a wrapper script named ctags which will switch the tool depending on `--language`.

Comment: Installing it seems to require a bit of work. And it looks like the package isn't being actively maintained: https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsctags, https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs

But good stuff!

Answer (score 5):

You can setup new languages for ctags. See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/george_v_reilly/archive/2009/03/24/exuberant-ctags-and-javascript.aspx) and [that](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html)

Comment: +1, but this answer would be better if the "this" content were included here for reference (with a source citation).

Answer (score 1):

provided you install doctorjs, you can use the vim-taglist-plus plugin, which is a fork of the vim-taglist plugin with jsctags (doctorjs) support : https://github.com/int3/vim-taglist-plus