# Taglist plugin does not show Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, vim, taglist

I'm using a `taglist` plugin for a few days and now I tried it with Javascript, but in Javascript it shows only partial information or no information. It seems that the problem could be with namespaces, because the functions are in

```
var namespace_name = {

f1: function() {
},
f2: function() {
},
.
.
.

};
```

or this sort of functions (anonymous)

```
var something = (function f() {
   }
   ...
})();
```

Do you know how to correct this problem?

thank you

Comment: There's a `=` missing between `namespace_name` and `{`, a `;` missing after the last `}` and the last `,` is not allowed here in JavaScript.

Comment: @romainl Syntax is OK. I have this problem with all javascript files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465)? It's a more modern take on the same idea which works better with JavaScript and even supports jsctags.

[image: taglist on the left, tagbar on the right]

TagList on the left, TagBar on the right.

TagList doesn't work because Exuberant ctags (the program used by TagList to index your code) is not very good with JavaScript, especially the modern stuff with callbacks, closures and self executing functions.

On the other hand, TagBar uses jsctags for JavaScript if it's available. Jsctags is made with modern JavaScript in mind and as such works a lot better.

Compare these tag files generated against the following code (based on your samples):

```
var namespace_name = {

    f1: function() {
        window.alert("f1");
    },
    f2: function() {
        window.alert("f2");
    }
};
var something = (function f() {
    window.alert("something");
})();
```

Output of `$ ctags .`:

```
// empty file expect for the header
```

Output of `$ jsctags .`:

```
// skipped header
namespace_name  test.js /^var namespace_name = {$/;"    v   lineno:1    type:Object
f1  test.js /^\tf1: function() {$/;"    f   lineno:3    type:void function()
f2  test.js /^\tf2: function() {$/;"    f   lineno:6    type:void function()
f   test.js /^var something = (function f() {$/;"   f   lineno:11   type:void function()
something   test.js /^var something = (function f() {$/;"   v   lineno:11   type:undefined
```

There are a bunch of questions on SO about customizing exuberant ctags to make it work  better with JavaScript: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477322/how-to-make-vim-ctags-works-for-modern-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790623/how-can-i-make-vims-taglist-plugin-show-useful-information-for-javascript).

So, basically, there are two ways to solve your problem: customize ctags or use tagbar+jsctags.

Comment: It shows correctly functions in namespace but still has problems with many functions. I will edit question.

Comment: There are too many `}` in your sample. But it doesn't really change anything. See my edit.

Comment: Is jsctags still available to download from somewhere?

Comment: Yes you can download it from [its official github page](https://github.com/evilpie/jsctags).

Comment: @romaini I installed jsctags, but when I use it according to [usage](https://github.com/evilpie/jsctags) section, it writes error `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`. I can't accept this question before I don't solve this error. Should I ask another question or is this something trivial?

Comment: It looks like you didn't install node which is required by jsctags. You must first install node, add its location to your `$PATH` if needed, then install jsctags. If node is installed, you probably forgot to update your `$PATH`. I won't be available this week-end so if you need further assistance you'll have to ask another question. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I installed node.js as a package in Ubuntu but I don't know where it could be installed (the path to node.js)

Comment: The usual way to know where some executable is installed is `$ which node` but I doubt it will give you valuable info at this point. You could launch Synapic, search for "node", right-click and choose properties, then look at the "Installed files" tab. I've installed it manually and ended up with a `/home/romainl/node` directory which I added to my `$PATH`. This location is neither clean nor standard but it works well for my limited needs: no interest for nodejs per se, only needed it for `jsctags`.

Comment: `nodejs` is located at `/usr/bin` which is in `$PATH`. I'm still getting [this](http://pastebin.com/MJjnHUJL) error and don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Your problem with running jsctags/nodejs has a lot more to do with jsctags and nodejs than with Vim and TagList/TagBar. I suggest you try their respective support channels or ask a separate question here on SO. We are deviating a lot from the original issue. I think your original question is answered in principle (TagBar + jsctags is right now the best way to have correct code-navigation with JavaScript in Vim) if not actually (the tools don't seem to work on your machine), but feel free to leave this question open, I'm not desperate for reputation points.

Comment: Did you try the alternate path of customising ctags itself through its config file?

Comment: OK, I will ask another question. Thank you for support